# how to customize a jquery mobile dialog

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-dialog

How do I remove the default formatting of the dialog box and apply my own CSS?

My attempt isn't working very well...

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="confirm-clear" class="dialog-custom" >
    <div data-role="content" >
        <p>Some text.</p>
        <p><a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Yes</a><a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back">No</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
And in my CSS:

```
.ui-dialog.dialog-custom {

background: repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);

height:200px; /* this doesn't do anything */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQM uses a variety of styles to achieve its theming, such as webkit gradients and background images with background-position offsets. It also wraps some elements in divs or inserts spans etc for layout.

To start you will need to use a debugger such as Chrome's developer tools and inspect the dialog, under computed style you can see your styles and whether they are being overridden or their effect. You can also see any extra layout elements jQM inserts and turn off jQM's styles until your styles come into effect.

Now you can start overriding jQM's styles by using !important, or modifiying jQM's CSS files

Comment: Please see the edit in the original post. How can I make the div not take up the entire height of the screen?

Comment: This isn't easy to edit, why do you need to? Like Jasper said jQM overrides the height, a dialog is meant to take up the entire screen and it's modal anyways.

Also jQM handles cross-mobile browser issues, so its not guaranteed your solution through editing jQM's resize event will work for all phones.

I've learned to just work with what I've got, you'll still find enough discrepancies even with jQM (e.g. keypress on Android Firefox) to be wary editing jQM

Answer (score 0):

CSS uses the most unique selector by default, and jQuery Mobile is probably using a more unique selector. You can use the `!important` keyword to make sure that your CSS declarations are used:

```
.ui-dialog.dialog-custom {
    background : repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    height     :200px !important;
}
```

If you inspect elements with developer tools like Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug, you can see what styles are being applied and what CSS rule they come from. This will help you decide the best way to add styles to an existing framework.

I'm not sure about dialogs but for page widgets, the `min-height` CSS property of the element is altered via the jQM framework. You can work-around this by over-writing the jQM `resize` event handler for dialogs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. !important doesn't help. Can you explain how to "work-around this by over-writing the jQM resize event handler for dialogs."

Comment: Firebug just shows this for the dialog: element.style {
    height: 687px;
}, which changes as the window is resized.

Comment: @soleil Off the top of my head I think the easiest way is to bind an event handler to the `resize` event for the `window` object that has a timeout to size the dialog how you want. `$(window).bind('resize', function () {setTimeout(function () { $('#my-dialog').height(200); }, 500);})`